# Attach Controller to $http html data?

Tags: angularjs

What I want to do is to load separated templates and append a controller to each one:

an approach:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'templates/myTemplate.html',
    controller:'myCtrl'
})

function myCtrl($scope){
    $scope.var1= "scoped variable";
}
```

myTemplate.html:

A Tag

{{var1}}

that is an aproach to this question:
[Loading an AngularJS controller dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250644/angularjs-loading-a-controller-dynamically)

Comment: Could you clarify your question and explain what you are trying to achieve? Give an example of the expected result if possible.

Comment: i've just edited the question.

Comment: You can add the ng-controller directive to any element once it's part of the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your scenario would be a good place to apply [`ng-include`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude).  For example, given this markup:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-include="template"/>
</div>
```

and this code in `MainCtrl`:

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
  // some logic that would determine the template you want to load
  $scope.template = 'templates/myTemplate.html';
}
```

and this code in `templates/myTemplate.html`:

```
<div ng-controller="TemplateCtrl">
     <!-- Template Content -->
</div>
```

angular will automatically download `templates/myTemplate.html` and apply `TemplateCtrl` to the template.  (Of course you'd also need to have `TemplateCtrl` defined.)   When you want to switch templates, in `MainCtrl` you'll need to change the value of `$scope.template` to another template url; that template would specify an `ng-controller` attribute that indicates the appropriate controller for that template.

Comment: Great!, I guess this is the way to go!