# loop through all controllers on the angular object

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to from the global `window` or `window.angular` object loop through all controllers/modules/factories etc. that we have created and is being bootstrapped?

I'm thinking something like:

```
for(module in window.angular.modules) {
  for(ctrl in module.controllers) {
    console.log(ctrl);
  }
  for(factory in module.factories) {
    console.log(factory);
  }
  ...
}
```

Goal: I want to auto-generate some documentation for the app we've created.

**Edit:**
Note that we are not creating global objects when doing controllers. We are registring them directly on the module:

```
angular.module('ourApp')
  .controller('CustomerCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) { ... } ]);
```

Comment: Try also to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250644/angularjs-loading-a-controller-dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angular module contains an attribute called `_invokeQueue`, that contains an array of all the submodules that are part of this module.

```
console.log(angular.module('ourApp')._invokeQueue);
```

prints something like

```
[
    ['$provide', 'factory', Arguments['myFactory', ['$dependency1', '$dependency2', function(){}],
    ['$provide', 'service', Arguments['myService', ['$dependency1', '$dependency2', function(){}]
    ['$provide', 'constant', Arguments['myConstant', ['$dependency1', '$dependency2', function(){}]
    ['$controllerProvider', 'register', Arguments['myController', ['$dependency1', '$dependency2', function(){}]
    ...
]
```

**Note:** If you're building a documentation generation app, then in my opinion you shouldn't loop all registered modules, since there are many built-in angular modules (`ng`, `ngRoute`, etc) that you probably don't care about. You should instead specify which modules you want to document.

Comment: console.log(angular.module('ourApp')._invokeQueue); I get only the current module not all the parent. BTW is there a way to get the module name dynamically @Cotten sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Run in browser console:

To get list of registered controllers from angular application

```js
angular.module('appname')._invokeQueue.filter(function(comp){return comp[0] === '$controllerProvider'}).forEach(function(ctrl){console.log(ctrl[2][0]);})
```

To get list of registered providers from angular application

```js
angular.module('appname')._invokeQueue.filter(function(comp){return comp[0] === '$provide'}).forEach(function(ctrl){console.log(ctrl[2][0]);})
```