# AngularJS invokeQueue and configBlocks

Tags: angularjs

AngularJs Source code deep dive - What does `invokeQueue` and `configBlocks` do during angularjs bootstrapping? I see they are passed to arguments for `runInvokeQueue` function inside `loadModules`.

Answer (score 2):

`configBlocks` stores the list of services instantiated during module configuration:

```
angular.module("ng")._configBlocks[0][0]
```

`invokeQueue` stores the list of methods invoked after the module is loaded:

```
var foo = angular.module("ng");
foo.constant(alert)
foo._invokeQueue[0]
foo._invokeQueue[0][2][0]
```

> The `module` definition is situated at the first lines of AngularJS source. As the documentation says, the life span of every `module` operation can be divided into two phases. The `config` phase and the `run` phase. The object exposed by calling the angular.module() constructor provides us with these two methods. The functionality of the run method is pretty obvious out of the source. It simply puts the `config` function passed to the private list of `run` blocks. The `config` method, on the contrary, is not so obvious. Here is, what the `config` method does:
>
> The `invokeLater` private method inserts the combination of `provider` and its method to the internal module queue to be invoked later during the injector instantiation. The modules would be totally useless, if it weren't for the injector. The `CreateInjector` function is the concrete implementation and it has the private method `loadModules`.
>
> The `loadModules` function does, among other, the kickoff of modules which are passed to it. It returns one array of all the `run` blocks of all modules which are dependent on each other. The injector calls them through its `invoke` method. Last but not least, the `loadModules` function, during its iteration through all dependent modules, calls their functions stored at `_invokeQueue` and `_configBlock` respectively. The `run` blocks are called in the last position. This means all services and methods of the modules are already exposed and ready for use. On the contrary, the `config` method only works with providers exposed by the module. The constructors of the providers are stored in the `_invokeQueue` of the module.
>
> Two injectors
>
> The first injector, that is not exposed publicly, is an injector of providers. The second one is an instance injector. The instance injector asks the provider cache for the constructors needed. Then it calls the proper part of the provider and creates an instance. The instance injector searches in the provider cache before asking for the provider injector. The `module.provider` method exposes the provider injector's provider method, which at a closer look says a lot about the life cycle of services.
>
> Even other parts of angular constructs, like directives and controllers, are registered as providers in the provider's cache. The $compileProvider itself is then registered like any other provider through `$provide.provider` method. As a matter of fact, `module.factory`, `module.service` and `module.provider` store an instance in the provider cache as a first step. But it is an instance injector that we have at our disposal. The instance injector asks the provider cache as a first step and then calls the invoke method, which takes care of the dependencies.

**References**

- [Modules and injector](https://www.slideshare.net/EyalV/modules-and-injector)
- [Configuring a Provider](https://oricalvo.wordpress.com/2015/02/23/configuring_provider/)
- [fix(injector): invoke config blocks for module after all providers](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/c0b4e2db9cbc8bc3164cedc4646145d3ab72536e)
- [Loading an AngularJS controller dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250644/1113772)