# How to load AngularJS controller file on content loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to `Angular.JS` and i'm trying to load a controller file dinamically when a content loaded from `ng-include` is requesting it, i do this way because the page i'm building will have multiple controllers and i rather make the initial page to load fast due to it's size, i am not sure to do this and i thought i would achieve it by just doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/controllerFile.js"></script>
```

inside the content loaded.

the controller File is like this

```
app.controller('parseQuery', function()
{
    this.object = 'Enter query and parse.';

    this.parse = function()
    {
        this.object = JSON.stringify(window.getParam(this.query), null, '\t');
    };

    this.getURL = function()
    {
        this.query = document.URL;
        this.parse();
    };
});
```

the `html` file calls the controller with `ng-controller` as it should work. But when the content is loaded, javascript returns an error `Argument 'parseQuery' is not a`, so nothing works, how can i achieve to load a controller file after application is already bootstraped?

Comment: Angular cannot lazy load controllers (or services, or anything else angular) after having been bootstrapped. Out of the box anyway. You could take a look at https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad or wait for Angular 2 which will support lazy loading.

Comment: @jlowcs So i have no choice but to load all controllers in the initial page?

Comment: i am quite sure your total code size is much less then angular.js itself, which must be loaded for sure - so whats the point?

Comment: @nosthertus yes. Although, especially if minified and gzipped, your code shouldn't be very heavy. Lazy loading is usually necessary mostly for large apps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS: Loading a controller dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250644/angularjs-loading-a-controller-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

To lazy load your scripts, you'll want to check out an `AMD` or `CommonJS` loader. These libraries provide the ability to load scripts on demand.

Dan Wahlin has an [excellent blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs) detailing how to use `RequireJS` with angular.

In the [1.3.14 AngularJS recieved support for `CommonJS`](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2015/02/new-angularjs-releases-140-beta5-and.html). That will be your best bet.