# AngularJS rendering process

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Im working in a not good JS project, the page rendering is make with a JQuery function.

```
$("#sameID").html(data);
```

And using this the guys here can load a .html page (I know, its very bad, but this can't be changed now)

So, using this function the script make a get request on the following html page:

test.html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <h2>Todo {{1 + 1}}!</h2>
</div>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

index.js

```
app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

But I'm always facing this error if I remove the `<div ng-app="myApp">` works.

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Comment: So if you remove the `<div ng-app="myApp">` it gives an error, but if you put it back it works? Wouldn't the obvious solution be to... just... keep it? What's the end goal here?

Comment: @VoteyDisciple If I remove works, if I keep it doesn't works and the errors appers (My bad)

Answer (score 0):

You have to dynamically bootstrap your module with [angular.bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap):

```
<div id="sameID"></div>
<script>
  $(function() {
    var hardCodedHtml = "<div><h2>Todo {{1 + 1}}!</h2></div>";
    var parentElement = $('#sameID');
    parentElement.html(hardCodedHtml);
    angular.bootstrap(parentElement[0], ['myApp']);
  });
</script>
```

Running sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/D3B72neDa8uIDFpAlVcr?p=preview

Comment: @FabioPicheli That's odd. Have you re-tested it? Can you submit a JSFiddle or Plunkr with your code?

Comment: Yes, if I put the code in fiddle works fine, but the main problem in the JQuery request to load the .html, i think same stuff is loading first (idk), I tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250644/loading-an-angularjs-controller-dynamically) way, but Its not a good "work arround"

Comment: @FabioPicheli Now I see your problem. You have to use angular.bootstrap function. I updated the answer, check it out and let me know whether it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular module creation done via:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  //dependencies..
}]);
```

And module retrieving via:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
```

From the Angular [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module):

> **Creation versus Retrieval**
>
> Beware that using `angular.module('myModule', [])` will create the
>   module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use
>   `angular.module('myModule')` to retrieve an existing module.