# injecting module when you have access only to a module variable

Tags: angularjs

Let's say you have a

```
var app = angular.module('Mod1',[])
```

and now you need to inject something else to that module, but you can't change that line, you only have access to the `app` variable.

So this won't work, right?

```
var mod2 = angular.module('mod2',[]).factory('$myService', function(){ 
       return { do: function(){alert('doing'); }
})

app.directive('foo',[$myService]) // $myService here is undefined
```

Of course you can always do:

```
injector = angular.injector(['mod2'])
$myService = injector.get('$myService')
```

Although I'm wondering if there's more elegant solution

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924503/angularjs-inject-module-after-app-initialization

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on when is your code actually run.
I tried [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nKktBt2qa2ORC6jfjNGd?p=preview) and it worked.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
```

myModule.js

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
myModule.service('MyService', function() {
  return {test: 'MyService'};
});

app.requires.push('myModule');

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','MyService', function($scope, MyService) {
  $scope.name = MyService.test;
}]);
```

index.html

```
<head>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="myModule.js"></script>
</head>
```

You need to add your extra modules after the app.js is loaded but within the same javascript execution sequence. Timeouts and async loading failed for me.

Comment: app.requires.push... something I've never seen before

Comment: app.requires is an array, push is just an array method