# Inject module dynamically, only if required

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I'm using Require.js in combination with Angular.js.

Some controllers need huge external dependencies which others don't need, for example, `FirstController` requires [Angular UI Codemirror](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-codemirror/). That's a extra 135 kb, at least:

```
require([
  "angular",
  "angular.ui.codemirror" // requires codemirror itself
], function(angular) {
  angular.module("app", [ ..., "ui.codemirror" ]).controller("FirstController", [ ... ]);
});
```

I don't want to have to include the directive and the Codemirror lib everytime my page loads just to make Angular happy.
That's why I'm right now loading the controller only when the route is hit, [like what's done here](https://github.com/ifyio/angularjs-lazy-loading-with-requirejs/).

However, when I need something like

```
define([
  "app",
  "angular.ui.codemirror"
], function(app) {
  // ui-codemirror directive MUST be available to the view of this controller as of now
  app.lazy.controller("FirstController", [
    "$scope",
    function($scope) {
      // ...
    }
  ]);
});
```

How can I tell Angular to inject `ui.codemirror` module (or any other module) in the app module aswell?
**I don't care if it's a hackish way to accomplish this, unless it involves modifying the code of external dependencies.**

**If it's useful:** I'm running Angular 1.2.0.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I have been trying to mix requirejs+Angular for some time now. I published a little project in Github ([angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy)) with my effort so far, since the scope is too large for inline code or fiddles. The project demonstrates the following points:

- AngularJS modules are lazy loaded.
- Directives can be lazy loaded too.
- There is a "module" discovery and metadata mechanism (see my other pet project: [require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy))
- The application is split into bundles automatically (i.e. building with r.js works)

How is it done:

- The providers (e.g. `$controllerProvider`, `$compileProvider`) are captured from a `config` function (technique I first saw in [angularjs-requirejs-lazy-controllers](https://github.com/matys84pl/angularjs-requirejs-lazy-controllers)).
- After bootstraping, `angular` is replaced by our own wrapper that can handle lazy loaded modules.
- The injector is captured and provided as a promise.
- AMD modules can be converted to Angular modules.

This implementation satisfies your needs: it can lazy-load Angular modules (at least the ng-grid I am using), is definitely hackish :) and does not modify external libraries.

Comments/opinions are more than welcome.

---

(EDIT) The differentiation of this solution from others is that it does not do dynamic `require()` calls, thus can be built with r.js (and my require-lazy project). Other than that the ideas are more or less convergent across the various solutions.

Good luck to all!

Comment: Great solution bro -- I'll study it the soon I have time. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have plans to make Angular + Require.js testable via E2E?

Comment: I will definitely make it testable some way. To be honest, I haven't tried Angular E2E testing yet.

Comment: Let me know when you have done it testable, I'll be waiting :)

Comment: Hi, I did some more updates, including testing with Karma. Code coverage support and detailed documentation is on the way!

Comment: Could you say, can your solution dynamically unload modules? For example if I need some module for some page, and when that page was closed I want to clear loaded module in order to free the memory. Maybe you could advice something...

Comment: @PashaTurok Unfortunately no, I have no suggestions on this (and it is a very interesting topic, as client side applications grow bigger).

Answer (score 7):

**Attention: use the solution by Nikos Paraskevopoulos, as it's more reliable (I'm using it), and has way more examples.**

---

Okay, I have finally found out how to achieve this with a brief help with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18365367/2083599).

As I said in my question, this has come to be a very hacky way. It envolves applying each function in the `_invokeQueue` array of the depended module in the context of the app module.

It's something like this (pay more attention in the moduleExtender function please):

```
define([ "angular" ], function( angular ) {
    // Returns a angular module, searching for its name, if it's a string
    function get( name ) {
        if ( typeof name === "string" ) {
            return angular.module( name );
        }

        return name;
    };

    var moduleExtender = function( sourceModule ) {
        var modules = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments );

        // Take sourceModule out of the array
        modules.shift();

        // Parse the source module
        sourceModule = get( sourceModule );
        if ( !sourceModule._amdDecorated ) {
            throw new Error( "Can't extend a module which hasn't been decorated." );
        }

        // Merge all modules into the source module
        modules.forEach(function( module ) {
            module = get( module );
            module._invokeQueue.reverse().forEach(function( call ) {
                // call is in format [ provider, function, args ]
                var provider = sourceModule._lazyProviders[ call[ 0 ] ];

                // Same as for example $controllerProvider.register("Ctrl", function() { ... })
                provider && provider[ call[ 1 ] ].apply( provider, call[ 2 ] );
            });
        });
    };

    var moduleDecorator = function( module ) {
        module = get( module );
        module.extend = moduleExtender.bind( null, module );

        // Add config to decorate with lazy providers
        module.config([
            "$compileProvider",
            "$controllerProvider",
            "$filterProvider",
            "$provide",
            function( $compileProvider, $controllerProvider, $filterProvider, $provide ) {
                module._lazyProviders = {
                    $compileProvider: $compileProvider,
                    $controllerProvider: $controllerProvider,
                    $filterProvider: $filterProvider,
                    $provide: $provide
                };

                module.lazy = {
                    // ...controller, directive, etc, all functions to define something in angular are here, just like the project mentioned in the question
                };
                module._amdDecorated = true;
            }
        ]);
    };

    // Tadaaa, all done!
    return {
        decorate: moduleDecorator
    };
});
```

After this has been done, I just need, for example, to do this:

```
app.extend( "ui.codemirror" ); // ui.codemirror module will now be available in my application
app.controller( "FirstController", [ ..., function() { });
```

Comment: Could you give an example what's inside `module.lazy = { ... }`?

Comment: Go with the solution by Nikos. I'm no longer using this.

Comment: Nikos' project is too comples, I can't get the idea :(

Answer (score 4):

The key to this is that any modules your `app` module depends on also needs to be a lazy loading module as well. This is because the provider and instance caches that angular uses for its $injector service are private and they do not expose a method to register new modules after initialization is completed.

So the 'hacky' way to do this would be to edit each of the modules you wish to lazy load to require a lazy loading module object (In the example you linked, the module is located in the file 'appModules.js'), then edit each of the controller, directive, factory etc calls to use `app.lazy.{same call}` instead.

After that, you can continue to follow the sample project you've linked to by looking at how app routes are lazily loaded (the 'appRoutes.js' file shows how to do this).

Not too sure if this helps, but good luck.

Comment: Yep, this helps in some way. Thanks.

Comment: Although I prefer the way I solved this problem (see answer), yours is also very good. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a directive that will do this:

https://github.com/AndyGrom/loadOnDemand

example:

```
<div load-on-demand="'module_name'"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with existing lazy load techniques is that they do things which I want to do by myself.

For example, using requirejs, I would like to just call:

```
require(['tinymce', function() {
   // here I would like to just have tinymce module loaded and working
});
```

However it doesn't work in that way. Why? As I understand, AngularJS just marks the module as 'to be loaded in the future', and if, for example, I will wait a bit, it will work - I will be able to use it. So in the function above I would like to call some function like loadPendingModules();

In my project I created simple provider ('lazyLoad') which does exactly this thing and nothing more, so now, if I need to have some module completely loaded, I can do the following:

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'lazyLoad', function($scope, lazyLoad) {

    // ........

    $scope.onMyButtonClicked = function() {

        require(['tinymce', function() {
            lazyLoad.loadModules();

            // and here I can work with the modules as they are completely loaded
        }]);
    };

    // ........

});
```

here is link to the source file (MPL license):
https://github.com/lessmarkup/less-markup/blob/master/LessMarkup/UserInterface/Scripts/Providers/lazyload.js

Answer (score 0):

I am sending you sample code. It is working fine for me. So please check this:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);

/* Module Creation */
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$controllerProvider', function ($routeProvider, $controllerProvider) {

app.register = {
    controller: $controllerProvider.register,
    //directive: $compileProvider.directive,
    //filter: $filterProvider.register,
    //factory: $provide.factory,
    //service: $provide.service
};


//    so I keep a reference from when I ran my module config
function registerController(moduleName, controllerName) {
    // Here I cannot get the controller function directly so I
    // need to loop through the module's _invokeQueue to get it
    var queue = angular.module(moduleName)._invokeQueue;
    for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
        var call = queue[i];
        if (call[0] == "$controllerProvider" &&
           call[1] == "register" &&
           call[2][0] == controllerName) {
            app.register.controller(controllerName, call[2][1]);
        }
    }
}


var tt = {
    loadScript:
function (path) {
    var result = $.Deferred(),
    script = document.createElement("script");
    script.async = "async";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = path;
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function (_, isAbort) {
        if (!script.readyState || /loaded|complete/.test(script.readyState)) {
            if (isAbort)
                result.reject();
            else {
                result.resolve();
            }
        }
    };
    script.onerror = function () { result.reject(); };
    document.querySelector(".shubham").appendChild(script);
    return result.promise();
}
}

function stripScripts(s) {
    var div = document.querySelector(".shubham");
    div.innerHTML = s;
    var scripts = div.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var i = scripts.length;
    while (i--) {
        scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
    }
    return div.innerHTML;
}


function loader(arrayName) {
    return {
        load: function ($q) {
            stripScripts(''); // This Function Remove javascript from Local
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
            map = arrayName.map(function (obj) {
                return tt.loadScript(obj.path)
                .then(function () {
                    registerController(obj.module, obj.controller);
                })
            });

            $q.all(map).then(function (r) {
                deferred.resolve();
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
};



$routeProvider
    .when('/first', {
        templateUrl: '/Views/foo.html',
        resolve: loader([{ controller: 'FirstController', path: '/MyScripts/FirstController.js', module: 'app' },
            { controller: 'SecondController', path: '/MyScripts/SecondController.js', module: 'app' }])
    })

    .when('/second', {
        templateUrl: '/Views/bar.html',
        resolve: loader([{ controller: 'SecondController', path: '/MyScripts/SecondController.js', module: 'app' },
        { controller: 'A', path: '/MyScripts/anotherModuleController.js', module: 'myapp' }])
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: document.location.pathname
        });
}])
```

And in HTML Page:

```
<body ng-app="app">

<div class="container example">
    <!--ng-controller="testController"-->

    <h3>Hello</h3>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#/first">First Page </a></td>
            <td><a href="#/second">Second Page</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>




        <div id="ng-view" class="wrapper_inside" ng-view>
        </div>
    <div class="shubham">
    </div>
</div>
```