# AngularJS directive loaded with RequireJS not compiling

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angularjs-directive

I'm in the beginning stages of building a large app with AngularJS and RequireJS. Everything loads find but directives aren't manipulating the DOM as they should. No errors are being reported and rest of the app works fine: Views are loaded and $scope is bindable. Examining the console shows that all the files loaded. I'm assuming this is a lazy load issue in that my directive is simply not loading at the correct time. I'd appreciate any insight into how to properly load directives in this regard. Unless it's a part of Angular's jqLite, please refrain from suggesting jQuery.

**config.js**

```
require.config({
  paths: { angular: '../vendor/angular' }
  shim: { angular: { exports: 'angular' } }
});
require(['angular'], function(angular) {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

**myApp.js**

```
define(['angular', 'angular-resource'], function (angular) {
  return angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);
});
```

**routing.js**

```
define(['myApp', 'controllers/mainCtrl'], function (myApp) {
  return myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    ...
  }]);
});
```

**mainCtrl.js**

```
define(['myApp', 'directives/myDirective'], function (myApp) {
  return myApp.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    ...
  }]);
});
```

**myDirective.js**

```
require(['myApp'], function (myApp) {
  myApp.directive('superman', [function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      template: '<div>Here I am to save the day</div>'
    }
  }])
});
```

**home.html**

```
<div class="superman">This should be replaced</div>
```

*home.html is a partial that's loaded into ng-view*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular cannot load directives after it has been bootstrapped. My suggestion is:

1. Make `myDirective.js` do a `define()`, not a `require()`
2. Make sure `myDirective.js` is run before the `require(['angular'],...)` statement in config.js, e.g. do `require(['angular','myDirective'],...)`. **For this to work, `myDirective` should be shimmed to depend on `angular` - thanks @ David Grinberg.**

As a sidenote, take a look at [this in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591966/inject-module-dynamically-only-if-required)/[this in GitHub](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy), we have been trying to do RequireJS + Angular play together.

Comment: Arrrr!!! Didn't even notice I was doing require instead of define. Struggled with this for ages. That solved it. Thanks a bunch. I'll definitely be looking at your Github project.

Comment: In your example in #2, isn't `myDirective` run after `angular`? Wouldn't this still not work? Also, how would you run it before? Wouldn't it complain that Angular isn't defined?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg You are very right. I forgot to say that for the 2nd case to work, `myDirective` should be shimmed to depend on Angular. Updating the answer. (Technically the order `angular` and `myDirective` would run is unspecified, RequireJS loads them asynchronously.)

Comment: Again you've stated 'Make sure myDirective.js is run before the...' But still in your edit you added that it should be simmed to depend on angular. Isn't it controversial, how can myDirective run before angular if it depends on it? What am i getting wrong?

Comment: According to solution provided by @Nikos `myDirective` should be defined before `MyApp` starts bootstraping. But `myDirective` holds `myApp` (which does a bootstraping) as a dependency and uses it to register itself, isn't that wrong?

Comment: @l0lander: For comment (1): I wrote: *Make sure myDirective.js is run before the require(['angular'],...) statement in config.js*. Not before Angular. By making the myDirective**.js** require `angular` (directly or by shimming), everything runs in order. For comment (2): `myApp` defines the main module. The bootstrapping is executed by the last statement of `config.js`.

Comment: @Nikos Pff of course man... sorry, i've lost my vision fighting with requirejs and angularjs. Thanks a tone!